# Why does the `operator<<` not work on member pointing to derived type?

Tags: c++, output, operator-overloading

I have a class `Base` with a member pointing to a derived type `Derv`:

```
class Derv;

class Base
{
protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derv>> opnds;
    ...
}
```

The derived class looks like this:

```
#include "Base.h"

class Derv:
    public Base
{
...
}
```

Now I want to `cout` all `Base` and derived types by serializing the items from `opnds`. I read that something like the following is the standard approach for that (since I might want to override the serialization from other derived classes). I included into `Base.h`:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, math_struct const &m);
virtual void serialize(std::ostream& os) const;
```

In `Base.cpp` I implemented:

```
#include <string>

void Base::serialize(std::ostream& os) const
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->opnds.size(); ++i) {
        os << ", " << *this->opnds[i]; // Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, math_struct const &m) {
    m.serialize(os);
    return os;
}
```

But the recursive application of `<<` in `Base::serialize` serialize doesn't work. It seems to have to do with the derived class being referenced in the base class member. An earlier version where I head `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> opnds` worked fine.

I'm new to C++, so probably I got something basic wrong...

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You didn’t tell `ostream` how to handle object of type `Derv`

Comment: -3. Wow, this is a bad question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if you have defined `Derv` before defining `serialize` because otherwise the compiler cannot know, that `Derv` can be cast to `Base`.

The following should do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base;
class Derv;


std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Base&);


class Base
{
public:
    void serialize(std::ostream& os) const;

protected:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Derv>> opnds;
};

// class Derv must be _defined_ before defining the functon Base::serialize!

class Derv : public Base { };


void Base::serialize(std::ostream& os) const
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < this->opnds.size(); ++i) {
        os << ", " << *this->opnds[i];
    }
}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Base&)
{
    out << "operator called" << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: You've been right all along, I finally figured it out. So far I only had a forward declaration of Derv. What I forgot (or to be exact, didn't realize) was that I had to include "Derv.h" (or define it right there like you did). Thanks for answering despite the overall negative response to my question. I get it now that the information I gave was not really sufficient.